# What is the best way to indicate repeated off diagonal elements in a matrix/array?

Tags: matrices, arrays

I'd like to typeset a matrix of the following kind: When the symbols involved are big, like, in place of `$r$`, suppose we had `$\mu(k-1)$` and in place of `$\lambda$`, we had `$\mu(k-2)$`, the matrix B below becomes very ugly, especially due to the `$\ddots$` looking so ugly.

Is there a nicer way to typeset a matrix like the one below.

[image: matrix]

---

I  have seen that the off diagonal entries are often replaced by a big and prominent entry if they are all same. I'd be happy if someone comes up with a trick to do that as well. Probably, it is something standard and I am unaware of it.

Comment: Well, people here can only give a _nicer_ way, if there is something to compare to. So, I would suggest you compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that produces the matrix you think looks very ugly, including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a very common problem with matrix patterns and to be honest, I don't like that `\<>dots` solutions at all. I have a strong opinionated view about such use and I tend to think that they don't work at super- and sub- diagonals of the matrix.

So no matter what the solution is, one should always choose to carry the message across as opposed to complying with some ugly standard. Therefore I usually go with one of the following solutions

1. Bite the bullet and typeset the matrix properly such that the dots are unambiguous.

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{amsmath}
   \begin{document}
   \[ AA^T = B = rI + 
   \begin{bmatrix}
   0       &\lambda &\ldots  &\lambda\\
   \lambda & 0      &\ddots  &\vdots\\
   \vdots  &\ddots  &0       &\lambda\\
   \lambda &\ldots  &\lambda &0
   \end{bmatrix}
   \]
   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]
2. Avoid confusing drawings and define meaningful (hopefully!) shortcuts, e.g. you can  define all ones matrix with blackboard 1 and subtract `I` from that instead of `J`. You don't gain a lot by replacing `(1-I)` by `J` in terms of document space.

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{bbm}
   \begin{document}
   \[ AA^T = B = rI + \lambda(\mathbbm{1}-I) \]
   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]
3. Draw it properly with any graphics package, TikZ, PSTricks, METAPOST etc. as given in [Diagonal dots spanning multiple lines/columns of a matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38833/3235)

Answer (score 8):

Here's an idea.  I sort of threw it together so manual adjustments to `p{3.5ex}` and `\scalebox{2}` will probably be necessary to get what you want.  There are likely better ways to accomplish the same thing.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\[
\left[
\begin{array}{*{5}{>{\centering$}p{3.5ex}<{$}}}
r   &   &   &\multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{\scalebox{2}{$\lambda$}}}   \\
    &   r   &   &   &\\
    &   &\ddots &   &\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{\scalebox{2}{$\lambda$}}}&&r&\\
    &   &   &   &r
\end{array}
\right]
\]

\end{document}
```

Which gives the following

[image: The result]

Comment: I am quite unconvinced with this answer though. But,  I appreciate your efforts.

Comment: This was what I was looking for when coming into this page. But I'm not fully convinced by the answer. Nice job though

Answer (score 5):

You want to convey the idea that the `\mu(k-1)` coefficients are repeated on the diagonal and that the other coefficients are all equal to `\mu(k-2)`. So why don't you try the following?

```
\[
AA^T=B=
\begin{bmatrix}
\mu(k-1) & \mu(k-2) & \mu(k-2) & \dots & \mu(k-2) \\
\mu(k-2) & \mu(k-1) & \mu(k-2) & \dots & \mu(k-2)\\
\hdotsfor{5} \\
\mu(k-2) & \dots & \mu(k-2) & \mu(k-2) & \mu(k-1)
\end{bmatrix}
=(\mu(k-1)-\mu(k-2))I_{v}+\mu(k-2)J_{v}
\]
```

(which probably will need to be split into two lines)

[image]

You might want to add a supplementary line of the form

```
\mu(k-2) & \dots & \mu(k-2) & \mu(k-1) & \mu(k-2) \
```

just before the last line.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `$\mu(k-1)$`, you could use `$\mu_{k-1}$` to save some space in each entry of your matrix.

As Peter has suggested, create a sample and let us know how you would like it changed. Then we could help you better.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use the package `nicematrix` which has functionalities for this problem. Tikz nodes are automatically created for each cell of the matrix and the dotted lines are drawn with Tikz.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\[\begin{pNiceMatrix}
\mu(k-1) & \mu(k-2) & \Cdots   & \mu(k-2) \\
\mu(k-2) & \Ddots   & \Ddots   & \Vdots   \\
\Vdots   & \Ddots   &          & \mu(k-2) \\
\mu(k-2) & \Cdots   & \mu(k-2) & \mu(k-1)       
\end{pNiceMatrix}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Too many dots. It is visually overwhelming. I suggest the usage of the three ordinary dots.