# smallmatrix using tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, fontsize, matrices, tikz-matrix

I wish to use `tikzpicture` instead of `smallmatrix`, because the former offers better control for dots via [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38833/diagonal-dots-spanning-multiple-lines-columns-of-a-matrix). However, the code

```
$\Z^4\!\xleftarrow{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,nodes in empty cells,right delimiter={]},left delimiter={[} ]{
    & & & & & \\ 1& & -1& & 1& \\ 1& & -1& & 1& \\ & 1& & -1& & 1\\};
\end{tikzpicture} }\!\Z^6$
```

returns errors (unless `tikzpicture` is outside of `\xleftarrow`). How do I get the output of

```
$\Z^4\!\xleftarrow{ \left[\!\begin{smallmatrix}&&&&&\vspace{6pt}\\ 1&&-\!1&&1&\\1&&-\!1&&1&\\ &1&&-\!1&&1\\\end{smallmatrix}\!\right]}\!\Z^6$
```

(everything tight and small) using `tikzpicture`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `ampersand replacement` to keep `&` unchanged.

```
\documentclass[border=7pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\newcommand*{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\begin{document}
  $\Z^4\!\xleftarrow{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
    \matrix (m) [
      matrix of math nodes,
      nodes in empty cells,
      right delimiter={]},
      left delimiter={[},
      ampersand replacement=\&, % <-- this is what you need
      nodes={scale=.5}]
      {
          \&   \&    \&    \&   \&   \\
        1 \&   \& -1 \&    \& 1 \&   \\
        1 \&   \& -1 \&    \& 1 \&   \\
          \& 1 \&    \& -1 \&   \& 1 \\
      };
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }\!\Z^6$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This cries for an `ampersand replacement`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bbm}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbbm{Z}}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}

$\Z^4\!\xleftarrow{\vcenter{\hbox{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,nodes in empty cells,right delimiter={]},
left delimiter={[},ampersand replacement=\&]{
    \& \& \& \& \& \\ 1\& \& -1\& \& 1\& \\ 1\& \& -1\& \& 1\& \\ \& 1\& \& -1\& \& 1\\};
\end{tikzpicture} }}}\!\Z^6$
\end{document}
```

[image]