# Citing only the toplevel work/work of works

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber, multiple-citations

How can I cite only a toplevel work with biber/biblatex?

the idea is to have a `literature.bib` containing the real entries eg

```
@Online{stack:tex,
  title = {\tex},
  url = {https://tex.stackexchange.com},
}
@Online{stack:tex:diaglines,
  title     = {math mode - Diagonal dots spanning multiple lines/columns of a matrix - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange},
  url       = {https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38833/diagonal-dots-spanning-multiple-lines-columns-of-a-matrix},
  urldate   = {2019-08-20},
  crossref = stack:tex,
  keywords  = {tool, stack:tex},
}
```

and a filter while generating the bibliography like

```latex
\printbibliography[%
notkeyword={tool},
type=Online,
title={Online Quellen}
]
```

but I am not sure how to do this without removing the tags from the main entry.

The reasoning is to provide the option to have a full bibliography for example for online publication and a reduced one for printed versions; also I prefer to have more citations inline the `tex` file, so I have the option to share more.
(This is loosely related to [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1580/attributing-contributions-to-academic-work-that-occur-in-stack-exchange))

EDIT: Add `MWEB`

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Online{stack:tex,
  title = {\tex},
  url = {https://tex.stackexchange.com},
}
@Online{stack:tex:diaglines,
  title     = {math mode - Diagonal dots spanning multiple lines/columns of a matrix - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange},
  url       = {https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38833/diagonal-dots-spanning-multiple-lines-columns-of-a-matrix},
  urldate   = {2019-08-20},
  crossref = stack:tex,
  keywords  = {tool, stack:tex},
}

\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\nocite{stack:tex:diaglines}% technical citation should only be added to the biliography

\printbibliography[%
notkeyword={tool},
type=Online,
title={Online Quellen}
]

\end{document}
```

where I probably need to adapt the restrictions on the `printbibliography` or the `\jobname.bib`, to have only the `stack:tex` citation in the printed bibliography.

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me. Can you please make a complete [MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/87678) and show the output you'd like?